# python: use 'MySQLdb' module to connect to remote mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, linux

I have two virtual machines. One is used as Agent, One is used as Master. A Mysql Server is installed on Master(Mysql Client is forbidden to be installed on Master which means I can't use mysql command line on Master). The Mysql server has a default user 'root'. Now I want to write a python script which use 'MySQLdb' module on Agent. The test code is easy. just see as bellow:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

def main():
    try:
        conn=MySQLdb.connect(host=master ip,user='root',passwd='xxx',db='xxx',port=3306)
        cur=conn.cursor()
        count = cur.execute('select * from table')
        print count
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
    except MySQLdb.Error,e:
        print "Mysql Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

however, when I execute it on Agent, there is an error:
**Mysql Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root@Agent ip'(using password: YES)**

So I don't know why the user is '**root@Agent ip**', not the default user of Mysql server on Master. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: why you set host=master ip ?

Comment: You have specified the user name by `user='root'` and mysql use `username@host` as the user, so the user is `root@Agent_ip`. It's not an issue of `MySQLdb`, you would have the same issue if you log in with a mysql client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command named `GRANT` in MySQL. You have to grant permission for root@AgentIP (Where AgentIP is the IP of the system from which you have to access the db.)

The command to be run in the mysql client of the server:

```
GRANT ALL on mydb.* to 'root'@'YourIP' identified by 'YourPassword'
```

Only then the MySQL server running in the remote system will grant access to the database.

If not sure of the IP details, you can also specify 'root'@'%' ,

which will allow all requests from user named root from anywhere. This is not a recommended way, but there is such an option.

Comment: Since mysql client is forbidden to be installed on Master, is there any other method to grant remote user access?

Comment: @liminche : Or you can also grant access with the help of phpmyadmin. But there is no option for remote access without granting permissions